# Why request localization does not work when "Accept-Language" header is "en"?

Tags: c#, request, localization, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to add request localization to my ASP.NET Core Web Api project. After configuring the setup, localization works only for full "Accept-Language" headers like "ru-RU" or "en-US" but doesn`t work for "en", "ru" headers, however, I added them to Supported Cultures list.

I added 3 files to my Resources folder: ("Resources.resx", "Resources.ru-Ru.resx", "Resources.en-US.resx")

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {

       ...

        var supportedCultures = new[]
        {
            new CultureInfo("en-US"),
            new CultureInfo("en"),
            new CultureInfo("ru-RU"),
            new CultureInfo("ru"),
        };
        app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
        {
            DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("uk"),
            SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
            SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
        });

        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

I expect the server to localize the response when "Accept-Language" header is "ru" or "en"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I fixed the problem when renamed my resources files like:

```
"Resources.resx" -> "Resources.uk.resx", 
"Resources.ru-Ru.resx" -> "Resources.ru.resx", 
"Resources.en-US.resx" -> "Resources.en.resx"
```

Answer (score 0):

You were looking to use neutral cultures, but all your resource files were for specific cultures.

A culture with both language and region (like *en-US* or *ru-RU*) is called a specific culture. A neutral culture is language-only, like *en* or *ru*.

Your original set of resource files were all specific cultures. When you receive a request from a specific culture, Request Localization looks for that specific culture. If it can't find one, it will then try to find a neutral culture that corresponds to that specific culture. (This behavior can be disabled in RequestLocalizationOptions by setting FallbackToParentCultures to false)

By renaming them, you changed them into neutral cultures. Since you have no specific cultures defined anymore, a request for *en-US* will always fallback to matching *en*. If you're not localizing for culture (as in, no separate localization for American vs British), this is a perfectly good solution.